# Blender Animated VFX

Tags: animation, effects

I was wondering how I would go about animating something in blender and putting it on live action footage. Like if I were to animate a ship flying and need to insert it into a live action clip in after effects, would I angle the camera in blender the same as it is in the live action clip and render it with a green background so I can key out the animation then just do my thing in after effects to make it look like it fits? That's my guess but I am happy to hear any suggestions.

Comment: from what I understand you want to do camera tracking? In that case you need to import your clip, put some markers in order to find the perspective, put the ship where it is supposed to be, then render with transparent background. The key words for a search are "carmera tracking"

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to start with [Mr Dodo Bird](https://www.youtube.com/c/mrdodobird/videos) (Ian Hubert) on YouTube. [Blender Motion Tracking](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY8Ol2n4o4A) is probably the best short intro to Motion Tracking out there.

Comment: The one thing in stuck on is finding a good tutorial on putting blender animations over an already shot live action clip. Every tutorial is doing a live action character on top of a green screen and using blender to make the background. I'm trying to do the opposite in putting an animated figure over a live action background. Is the solution the same for these?